# Move workflow and attached document to site with same structure as source site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

Need to move a document in a document library from source site to another SharePoint 2010 site which has the same structure as the source site along with the workflow attached to the document. The workflow creates tasks too. So the tasks should be created in the tasks list in the destination site too. How to do this? I am doing a POC on this. Please share any ideas or documentation on this and any help will be appreciated.

Copying workflow as a template will not work here I guess. I need to copy actual workflow association to the document.

Comment: assuming that WF was created via SPD, is it by any way Reusable, or list attached?

Comment: if it is a spd workflow, do you think is it possible to move the workflow association with the document?  Basically i need to move a document from one site to another with the workflow association with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe consider building a Reusable Workflow associated with a Content Type (e.g. associate it to the default Document Content type) and then you could export the Worflow as a solution package (.wsp) which you could install on the other site (see here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608128(v=office.14).aspx)

One Document (.docx, .pptx, .pdf, etc.) is actually an Instance of a particular content type (Document) and Workflows cannot be attached to a Single List item, but rather to a List, a Content Type or it could be a Site Workflow.

Comment: Hi this copies the template right? i want to move workflow association to a document, if it has created tasks include them too.. including the current status of the workflow, include the document to an another site which has same structure as source site...

Comment: not possible really to that extent. And even with a Visual Studio built Workflow wouldn't really work as the complexities are quite big.